# How to call this function that checks if a message as been received and then sends response?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, webhooks

I have this function that runs fine on its own but when I try to call to it in another program it doesnt work, I want to use it to check if a message has been received and then respond if one has.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods =['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    number = request.form['From']
    m_b = request.form['Body']
    response_message='unknown response, type KEW for a list of known words'
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    print(m_b)
    if m_b=='hello' or m_b== 'Hello':
        response_message='Hi,how are you?'
         
    elif m_b=='KEW' or m_b== 'kew' or m_b== 'Kew':
        response_message='hello, ..... yeh thats only one i have set up so far im still testing it'

    resp.message(response_message)

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the program its being called in

```
def bot():
    
       
    timer=time.time()
    sold_out=True 
    
    print('Bot is starting')                                                                                                                                                                         
    print('Loading item page')
    still_running_check=0        
    while sold_out==True:                                                                                                                                       #while item is sold out reload the page and print sold out to the console
       driver.get(item_url)                      
       #time.sleep(1)
       sold_out=check_exists_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/button")                                   
       still_running_check+=1
       sms_reply()
       #if still_running_check%100==0:
           #sms('Bot is still running and is on attempt '+str(still_running_check)+'\n '+str(round((time.time()-timer)/60,2))+' minute(s) have passed')
       if sold_out==False:
           break
       else:
           print ("Sold out")
    
    cart_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fulfillment-add-to-cart-button")                                                                   #once sold out is no longer true add to cart button is clicked
    cart_button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/checkout/r/fast-track")                                                                                             #navigates to checkout page
    time.sleep(1)
    code= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="credit-card-cvv"]')                                                                                        #csv input location
    code.send_keys(security_code)                                                                                                                           #inputs previously given csv code
    time.sleep(2)
    #confirm_button= driver.find_element_by_class_name("button--place-order-fast-track")
    #confirm_button.click()
    
    print('Order submission screenshot saved as "OrderSubmission.png" in repository location')                                                              #order completion code
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('OrderSubmission.png')
    sms('Bot Program executed succesfully for '+title.text)
    end=input(title.text+' program executed succesfuly hit enter to exit browser or type retry to start bot again:')                                                    #if program ran all the way through will print program ran succesfully
    if end=='retry':
                bot()
```

this returns the error "Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem."

I looked in the flask documentation and saw this
"This should typically only happen when testing code that expects an active request. One option is to use the test client to simulate a full request. Or you can use test_request_context() in a with block, and everything that runs in the block will have access to request, populated with your test data."

but I don't really understand what its saying and how to implement that into my code

Comment: Please provide more information than "it doesn't work"

Comment: Where does `request` come from?  Ordinarily, I would expect `request` to be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Are you running the Flask app?

Comment: I added more context to the question hopefully it is lest confusing now, sorry. I'm still relatively new to this forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your first function, `sms_reply`, looks as though it is set up to [receive an incoming webhook from Twilio when an SMS message is sent to your Twilio phone number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml). The function receives an incoming HTTP request, checks the body of the message, constructs a reply and returns it as the response to the request.

The problem is that you are then trying to call that function, which is expecting to respond to an HTTP request, inside your second bit of code, which does not seem to have an HTTP request related to it at all.

You might find that you want to use the Twilio REST API if you want to [list messages that you have received](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources) or [send a message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource). I'm not sure exactly what your code is trying to do, so I can't be more specific than that.